# ASP.NET Handler, manual threads and COM servers

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, com

I'm working on a legacy application where an ASP.NET HttpHandler is running its own threadpool which loads its own instances of out of process COM objects. Requests come in and pass a workload to these COM objects and when complete return the results.

The processing works fine and you definitely see the pool is working as simultaneous requests come in are processed reliably... as long as the pool thread count stays under 10 and the pool is not saturated with busy request. Once the pool saturates neither COM requests, nor plain ASP.NET Handler requests hit the ASP.NET pipeline any more, until the pool frees up an instance.

When I run the threadpool with 16 instances and hit the server with long running (waiting) requests that take 5 seconds to complete,  I can see exactly 10 instances get loaded up with work. Any instances beyond that are never hit. Not only that - even straight handler requests that don't hit the COM pool  also start queuing at this point.

More info:

- COM Pool is created with MTA Threads (but STA doesn't change anything)
- COM objects are STA threaded and out of process EXEs
- COM objects execute on the same fixed thread they were created on (ie. there's no COM thread marshalling)
- ASP.NET thread signals the Pool thread to start processing
- Currently the ASP.NET Context gets passed to the pool thread
- Running .NET 4.5
- Testing on Windows 10 Pro

The reason I use a custom thread pool is because of the COM dependency and the need to ensure the COM objects stay loaded on the same thread without COM marshalling. As mentioned it works fine until the point were all instances are busy and only then does everything stop until the pool frees up a new instance.

I can understand that the COM objects might be blocked, but I really don't get why the main ASP.NET thread would fail to process even a raw handler request (ie. I have a flag that runs a plain Response.Write() response  and returns and it sits and waits just like the COM requests when the pool is saturated)

I suspect it has to do with the COM object instantiation, but I'm baffled why this would occur when the objects are created on non-ASP managed threads.

Has anybody seen behavior like this where ASP.NET simply will not create new request threads and simply queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIS on a client OS (e.g. Windows 7) has limits on the number of concurrent connections. For instance, see http://forums.iis.net/p/1229666/2114928.aspx?Is+there+an+Concurrent+Request+Limit+on+IIS+8+5+.

Comment: Yup - just went and dumped the handler onto a live server and was able to verify that it works just fine there with all COM instances loading up and the raw handler immediately firing. Phew - I thought I was going nuts.

Comment: Sure wish they would remove those limits at least when you test against localhost IPs. This makes it really hard to develop load scenarios on the local machine unless you dev on a Server os :-(